# How can I make my creature's legs look fleshy?

Tags: materials

I'm creating the weird little creature below, but it's my first time modelling something organic and I can't seem to get the legs to look fleshy. They either look like plasticine (pictured) or like plastic, so I'm clearly missing something. I'm in Cycles and currently using Andrew Price's Dielectric PBR shader. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does the shader have subsurface scattering or fresnel? Are you in cycles?

Comment: If I was doing this with the internal renderer or OpenGL I'd add point lights close by and set the specular settings to "Wardlso" to give the tentacles an organic moist appearance with lots of tiny highlited reflections.  If necessary switch off the point lights' diffuse and increase the specular (including the 'Materials' specular) to whatever is necessary.  Adjusting the Bumping would help to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry, yes, this is in Cycles.

Comment: @10Replies It has Fresnel, but no scattering. If I add that, do I just use a mix shader to blend it to my current one?

Comment: @Danial yeah, just mix it with whatever you already have